# understanding e0507 error and trying to resolve

Tags: rust

I am in a `&mut self` function, I have a member field that is a `Vec<u8>`. I want to call a windows xxxA function (via the excellent winapi crate). I  have no choice on the `fn` signature, it is implementing a trait.

I think I need to make a `CString`. So I tried

```rust
fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        let str = CString::new(self.buf).unwrap();
        OutputDebugStringA(str.as_ptr());
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

this doesn't work.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.buf` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src\windbg.rs:51:36
   |
51 |             let str = CString::new(self.buf).unwrap();
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.buf` has type `std::vec::Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I've read the explain of this but none of the 3 suggested solutions seem possible.

Here is the whole struct:

```rust
struct WinDbgWriter {
    buf: Vec<u8>,
}
use std::io::Write;
impl std::io::Write for WinDbgWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.buf.extend_from_slice(buf);
        Ok(buf.len())
    }
    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        unsafe {
            let str = CString::new(self.buf).unwrap();
            OutputDebugStringA(str.as_ptr());
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: As error says that you cannot move object from a borrowed content. Instead you can build `CString` with slice: `CString::new(&self.buf[..])` . [This is the implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/ffi/c_str.rs.html#414) that shows you can build `CString` with slice, it basically does memcpy and creates new `Vec<u8>`. You can also use `self.buf.clone()` , it will do pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

If we take [your minimized case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dcc41ff6c4ab23a04baaed388465a155) and try to borrow `self.mut` to avoid moving it (transferring its ownership), [we get a new error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e303f7f41b9043726729e5ca4a683d7) which has a suggestion:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<u8>: From<&Vec<u8>>` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:9:33
    |
9   |         let _str = CString::new(&self.buf).unwrap();
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^
    |                                 |
    |                                 the trait `From<&Vec<u8>>` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`
    |                                 help: consider adding dereference here: `&*self.buf`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <Vec<T> as From<&[T]>>
              <Vec<T> as From<&mut [T]>>
              <Vec<T> as From<BinaryHeap<T>>>
              <Vec<T> as From<Box<[T]>>>
            and 6 others
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<Vec<u8>>` for `&Vec<u8>`
```

If we [follow that suggestion](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e303f7f41b9043726729e5ca4a683d7), or [explicitly coerce `self.buf` to a `&[u8]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d009eb79f603350f6e28cca9a6806f9), then the code compiles.

[`CString::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.new) takes an argument of some type `Into<Vec<u8>>`, but `self.buf` is, at this point of type `&Vec<u8>` because of it being accessed through a `&self` borrow, and there's no `impl Into<Vec<u8>> for &Vec<u8>`.